# Method to convert a long path name to a short path returns a null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to ensure I can download a file if it has a long file name. This is the class I'm using.

```
public class ShortFileName
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int GetShortPathName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string path,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    StringBuilder shortPath,
    int shortPathLength
    );
}
```

This is the code in my controller which implements the download.

```
 public ActionResult Download(string path, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder shortPath = new StringBuilder(255);

            ShortFileName.GetShortPathName(path, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);

            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(shortPath.ToString());

            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

shortPath is null when the file path is excessively long.

Comment: Can you update your question to show what is meant by "file path is excessively long" and then what would you want the expected outcome to be for the shortPath?

Comment: The `MAX_PATH` constant is defined at 260, so you should use a `StringBuilder(260)`. Unclear why you are the `GetShortPathName()`... You could set the `SetLastError = true` in the `DllImport` to get an exception describing the problem.

Comment: Do you need to support file paths that are longer that 260 characters?

Comment: Just a related note: Windows 10 now has a registry key where you can opt in to long file paths / remove the 260 max_path constraint

Comment: `byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(shortPath.ToString());
  return File(fileBytes,...` - don't do it unless you have _**very good reason**_ for it. Return that file as a Stream instead.. think about what will happen if you ever have a _**large file**_ to download.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. If you don't need to support original pathnames longer than 260 characters, you can remove all the code to do with `PREFIX`.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern uint GetShortPathName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string lpszLongPath,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    StringBuilder lpszShortPath,
    uint cchBuffer);

public static string ShortFilenameFor(string longFilename)
{
    // Add to the long filename a prefix to cause the API to handle filenames longer than 260 characters.

    const string PREFIX = @"\\?\";
    longFilename = PREFIX + longFilename;

    // First check how much space is required for the short filename.

    uint length = GetShortPathName(longFilename, null, 0);

    if (length == 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    // Now allocate buffer of the correct length and fill it.

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder((int)length);
    uint result = GetShortPathName(longFilename, buffer, length);

    if (result == 0)
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

    buffer.Remove(0, PREFIX.Length);
    return buffer.ToString();
}
```