# Windows Path Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I want to convert `"C:\Program Files\x\y\z"` to `"C:\%ProgramFiles%\x\y\z` OR `"C:\Progra~1\x\y\z"`(DOS short path). How to do this C#.Net?

To convert long path to DOS short path I have tried solution [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585171/getshortpathnamea-not-working-in-c-sharp) however on my Windows 10 it is not working. Any hints?

Update - Please note, path may or may not exist physically on disk. I am looking a solution which can convert any arbitrary path string to above formats. The solution using GetShortPathName(...) works only if the LongPath is physically exist on disk.

Comment: I don't think you want `C:\%ProgramFiles%\x\y\z` because %ProgramFiles% expands to e.g. *c:\program files* meaning you'll end up with a path of `c:\c:\program files\x\y\z`. Did you mean `%ProgramFiles%\x\y\z` ?

Comment: Yes. it is typo. I want same behavior as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a string put into your app such as "c:\program files\x\y\z" and you know it's the wrong place, but don't know where the right place is, you're going to have to make the assumption that `c:\program files` means "the program files folder" and perform a string replacement with the result of `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` or `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)` depending on which you assert it to be

```
var wrongPath = @"c:\program files\x\y\z";
var actualPath = wrongpath.Replace(
  @"c:\program files", 
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
);
```

For conversion to a short path, try something like: [Method to convert a long path name to a short path returns a null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792813/method-to-convert-a-long-path-name-to-a-short-path-returns-a-null)

Comment: The link for converting to short path using GetShortPathName(...) pinvoke works only if the long path exist on the machine. My requirement is to convert any arbitrary Path string to short path.

Comment: That's like saying "i want to know the path where the user will save a file, before he chooses where to save it". You cannot know the path that windows will shorten it to, hence why it needs to exist first. It could be the case that a file path in `c:\programs i love\xyz.txt` becomes `c:\progra~3\xyz.txt` because there is already `c:\program files -> c:\progra~1` and `c:\program files(x86) -> c:\progra~2` - you hence cannot arbitrarily decide what  any short path will be before you've written the file to disk, you have to place the file, then ask windows what the short path is